# Php match values between 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Guys i have a very awkward situation here , i am not sure whether am i taking a right approach or not.. i am trying to match the values between 2 arrays and then running if else statement... here's goes what i am trying to do

```
$array1 = array('html','php','js','css');
$array2 = array('php','python','html','java');
```

what i want is to make a check where the values of these 2 arrays matches to each other.
  like php and html is common in both and also where it doesn't match.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at PHP's built-in array functions. And maybe array-diff http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: By "match", do you merely mean that the variable is an element of both arrays, or do you also require that they occupy the same position in each array?

Answer (score 7):

You mean like an [intersection](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)?

Answer (score 7):

It's your need:

```
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

the result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => html
    [1] => php
)
```

Answer (score 5):

[array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

and

[array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

should do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

To get both the intersecting elements of the array and the differing elements use both [array_diff()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) and [array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).