# How to compare two array based on matched values and order in PHP?

Tags: php

I have 2 array, I want to compare them by matched values and order and count of total eligible values.

```
$a = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G];
          | |     |
$b = [B,A,C,D,F,E,G];
```

In this case the output should be **3** . How can I achieve this with top performance?

**Update:**

I am not asking matched values only , values should matched at the same order as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php match values between 2 arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038989/php-match-values-between-2-arrays)

Comment: I think this should do it `$result = array_intersect($a, $b);
print_r(count($result));`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5678990

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array_diff_assoc will count what is not the same (4).
Count will count the number of items (7).
7-4 = 3.

```
echo count($a) - count(array_diff_assoc($a,$b)); // 3
```

https://3v4l.org/OIknS

Edit or just array_intersect_assoc

```
echo count(array_intersect_assoc($a,$b)); //3
```

Didn't cross my mind until now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both arrays have the same size you can do it with a simple loop:

```
$count = 0;

foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    if ($value === $b[$key]) {
        $count++;
    }
}

var_dump($count);
```

If they have different sizes then you must check if the key exists in the second array too.